# Is L'Hopitals rule applicable to complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a question about something I'm wondering about. I've read somewhere that
L'Hopitals rule can also be applied to complex functions, when they are analytic.
So if have for instance:

$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(1+z)}{z} \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{(1+z)} = 1
$$

Now i'm wondering if this is correct? Also if we take $|z|<1$, is it then correct?

Thanks,

Comment: Your limit is just the derivative of $log(1+z)$ at $0$, and it is 1. What do you mean by taking $|z| < 1$? I think that we just care about a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: I heard that L'Hopitals rule can only be applied to analytic functions in a certain region. So if we have that $|z|<1$, then we get no problems with the definition of the $\log$ right?

Comment: By the way, if $f, g$ analytic at $a$, and $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, then $\lim_{z\to a} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \lim_{z\to a} \frac{f(z) - f(a)}{z-a}.\frac{z-a}{g(z)-g(a)} = \frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$.

Comment: Since you're interested in the limit at $0$, bounding the functions to the unit circle is irrelevant.

Comment: Both $\log(1+z)$ and $1/z$ are meromorphic at 0. For meromorphic functions the Laurent series of their product is the product of their Laurent series: so you have $$ z^{-1}\log(1+z) = z^{-1}(0 + z + O(z^2)) = 1 + O(z) $$ and is holomorphic.

Comment: The analyticity of log is not defined within a closed circle. You would need to choose a branch cut in order for log(1+z) to be an analytic function. Since you can't have log(0) then your branch point would be wherever (z+1) = 0 which is z = -1. Then your branch cut would extend from z = -1 and would have to avoid the point z=0 since you're taking the limit there. (I would use the principal branch $-\pi <\theta\le\pi$). (Also the reason we choose a branch cut is because log(z) is periodic and in order to be analytic, log(z) must be well-defined: have only one output for each input).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

L'Hopital's rule is a local statement: it concerns  the behavior of functions near a particular point. The global issues (multivaluedness, branch cuts) are irrelevant. For example, if you consider $\lim_{z\to 0}$, then it's automatic that only small values of $z$ are in play.  Saying "take $|z|<1$" is redundant.

Generally, you have a point $a\in\mathbb C$ and some neighborhood of $a$ in which   $f,g$ are holomorphic. If $f(a)=g(a)=0$, then 
$$\lim_{z\to a}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}=f'(a),\qquad \lim_{z\to a}\frac{g(z)}{z-a}=g'(a) \tag{1}$$
hence 
$$\lim_{z\to a}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}= \lim_{z\to a}\frac{f(z)/(z-a)}{g(z)/(z-a)} =\frac{f'(a)}{ g'(a)}$$
Note that the above is a  simple special case of  the L'Hopital's rule, because we have (1). It's basically just the definition of derivative.

Comment: We can use this when the limit goes to infinity, right ?

Comment: @Our Don't know if you still want to know, but I think it can be used. The function maybe not be holomorphic at the point, but should be holomorphic in the region around the point.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari thanks!