# Proving that $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{f^\prime(z)}{g^\prime(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, roots

> Let $f,g$ both analythic in neighbourhood of $z_0$ and they both have zero of multiplicity $n$ in $z_0$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{f^\prime(z)}{g^\prime(z)}$. You mustn't use l'hospital rule but rather prove it in this private case.

I thought using the tecnique [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions) but seems like it doesn't use the fact about the multiplicity of the zeros. I know that $\exists h(z),k(z)$ s.t $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^nk(z)\\ g(z)=(z-z_0)^nh(z)$$ but after substitution remain only $k(z),h(z)$ functions which are diffrent than $g(z),g(z)$. How can I prove this "private -case of l'hospital"?

Comment: Don't you also need the assumption that one of those limits exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is L'Hopitals rule applicable to complex functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that, but the answer there answers this question

Comment: also maybe this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2654916/575793

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First, prove the fact for $n=1$, then use induction.