# Singularity of $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 110 he asked to determine the nature of the singularity at $z=0$ of the function $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ and if it's a removable singularity he asked to define $f(0)$ so that $f$ is analytic at $z=0$.

**Question 1:**
If this function has an isolated singularity at $z=0$ I know how to prove this one is removable (it suffices to prove $\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=0$ from theorem 1.2 of the same section). The problem is why does this function have an isolated singularity at $z=0$ in the first place?

**Question 2:**
I have a solution manual that says the function is analytic at $z=0$ if we define $f(0)=1$, because $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1$ (why?)

Comment: Use the power series of $\sin(z)$.

Comment: important : forget all what you read, $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ doesn't have any singularity at $z=0$, because in complex  analysis we don't consider functions but analytic continuation of functions !

Answer (score 4):

Clearly the function 
$$
f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}
$$
is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$. Therefore $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z=0$ which is removable since
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\sin(z)=0
$$
So we can remove this singularity. Now we just need to extend $f$ in $z=0$ continuously which we can do using a special case of the l'Hopital rule (check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions) for example), so:
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\cos(z)=1
$$
Therefore by setting $f(0)=1$ we have continuously extended $f$ on $\mathbb C$ and removed the singularity.

Comment: that $\lim_{z \to 0} zf(z) = 0$ implies $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $0$ is the [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity), not so easy to prove. no the singularity is removable because $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$ and  $\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z)$ both exist, hence the function is holomorphic at $0$

Comment: @user1952009 the fact that $\lim_{z \to 0} zf(z) = 0$ implies that $f$ is holomorphicly **extendable** at $z=0$, since $f$ is not even defined at $z=0$ it is ofc also not holomophic. So we indeed have that $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z=0$ which is - as the quoted theorem says - removable. Now we just need to extend the function continuously and are done.

Comment: did you understand my comment ? I said proving the Riemann theorem on removable singularities is not so easy. it is much more easy to show that $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z)$ both exist, and hence with $f(0) = \lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$, $f'(0) = \lim_{z \to 0} f'(z)$,  the function $f(z)$ becomes holomorphic at $0$. @user190080

Comment: (and an important rule is that in complex analysis we don't consider functions but analytic continuation of functions)

Comment: @user1952009 then we possibly talked past each other. If you don't want to use Riemann's theorem and instead use your property (you may want to add a reference) then this is perfectly fine, but OP has already stated the mentioned theorem and wants to make use of it, and that's also fine I'd say

Comment: given what you wrote, I'm quite sure you never proved that $f(z)$  holomorphic on $0 < |z| < \epsilon$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} z f(z) = 0$ implies that (the analytic continuation of) $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $0$. prove it (this is the theorem I'm referring to, that the OP didn't mention) and then compare with what I wrote.  @user190080

Comment: sorry didn't see, the theorem is mentionned, but you have to agree it is a theorem, not so easy to prove ! while what I wrote that $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$ and $\lim_{z\to 0} f'(z)$ exist imply $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $0$ is just the definition !! and you have to agree that many people use the word "removable singularity " and "essential singularity" or "pole" without having really defined and proved everything first, and without mentioning the needed theorems @user190080

Comment: @user1952009 no problem! besides, $f$ is holomorphic in any neighborhood of $0$ simply because it is a composition of holomorphic functions. And yes, the proof of Riemann's theorem might not be the easiest of all but is also standard. If you like, just also post an answer where you use a different approach, after all this is what this site is for.

Comment: @reuns  How to show that  if $ \lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$ and $\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z)$ both exist, then $ f(z)$ is holomorphic at $0$ ? Thanks a lot

Comment: It is the definition of holomorphic : complex differentiable on an open set. Perhaps you mean how to show it is analytic. Then it is the Cauchy integral formula. @Clin

Comment: @reuns  Thanks!  I mean how to show if $\lim_{z→0}f(z) $ and $ \lim_{z→0}f′(z)$ 
 both exist, then  $\lim_{z \to 0}\frac {f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}$ exist

Comment: This is the same as in real analysis l'Hospital rule. $f'(z) = C+o(1)$ and for $z \ne 0, f(z+s) = f(z)+s f'(z)+o(s)$ then $f(0)+z C = (f(z)-z f'(z)+o(z)) + (z f'(z)+o(z))= f(z)+o(z)$. @Clin

Answer (score 1):

It has an isolated singularity at $0$ because dividing by $0$ is undefined and thus $f(z)$ is not defined at $0$.

Second, there are two ways to think about this.

1) Since we already accept that this singularity is removable, the only way to define $f$ at $0$ is by its limit for else it would not be continuous and thus we would not have removed the singularity.

2) Going along the lines of the proof, $g(z)=zf(z)=sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots$.

Then, $g(z)=z(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\ldots)=zh(z)$ where $h(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\ldots$ is analytic.

Thus, as in the proof, we have to define $f(0)=h(0)=1$.