# Determing the type of singularity o $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{e^{-z}+z-1},\:z_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Determine the type of singularity of $z_0$ of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{e^{-z}+z-1},\:z_0=0$.

I tried to compute $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{e^{-z}+z-1}$ directly but I get the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. However in the solution it is stated $f(z)\sim\frac{2}{z}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{z}=0$

I do not understand the sort of solution that was presented to me via approximation.

**Questions**:

**1)** How is the approximation done? What is the procedure?

**2)** If I wanted to compute the limit, since I cannot use L'Hopital once $z$ is complex. How should I compute it then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: About L'Hôpital in the complex case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions, http://homepages.vub.ac.be/~gholland/ComplexeAnalysis/RuleHopitalComplex.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sin z = z - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \cdots$$
$$e^{-z} = 1 - z + \frac{z^2}2 + \cdots$$
$$e^{-z} + z - 1  = \cdots$$
$$
\frac{\sin z}{e^{-z} + z - 1} = 
\frac{z(1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots)}{z(\frac{z}{2} - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^3}{4!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} + \cdots)} =
\frac{2}z\,\frac{1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots}{1 - \frac{2z}{3!} + \frac{2z^2}{4!} - \frac{2z^3}{5!} + \cdots}
$$
And
$$
1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots,\qquad
1 - \frac{2z}{3!} + \frac{2z^2}{4!} - \frac{2z^3}{5!} + \cdots
$$
are analytic functions (convergent power series) with
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\, 1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots = \cdots
$$
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\, 1 - \frac{2z}{3!} + \frac{2z^2}{4!} - \frac{2z^3}{5!} + \cdots = \cdots
$$

Comment: I am not seeing how $e^{-z}+z-1=\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+....$ cancels with $\sin z = z - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \cdots$

Comment: @PedroGomes, what *means* your "cancels"?

Comment: I mean I am not seeing how the result can be $\frac{2}{z}$ since $e^{-z}+z-1$ has the odd and even exponents.

Comment: @PedroGomes, odd and even is irrelevant. The *size* is relevant. See the edit.

Comment: I am still not able to derive it. I am  not seeing how everything cuts or cancels out.

Comment: Could you please finish the derivation? I am stuck at $\frac{(z(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-...))}{z(\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^3}{4!}-\frac{z^4}{5!}...)}$. How do I get the expression from here, sorry but it is not clear to me.

Comment: @PedroGomes, the numerator is $1 +$ something smaller. The denominator is $z/2 +$ something smaller.

Comment: And then what should I do?

Comment: Should I eliminate the smaller part? How then?