# Proof of L'Hopital's rule for complex functions

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I was given the task to prove that if:

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0} g(z)=\infty$$

and:
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$$
exists, then the following is true:

$$\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}= \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f’(z)}{g’(z)}$$

AKA the proof for L'Hopital's rule for complex functions.
I tried using [Spivak's proof](https://planetmath.org/ProofOfLHopitalsRuleForInftyinftyForm) when the limit of the quotient of derivatives exists, but I didn't understand the transition that took part in this section:

[image]

So I was unable to complete the proof.
Could somebody please clarify or give an alternative explanation on this proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: No problem, sorry about that. I'm not sure how to insert formulas and equations here manually.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions#:~:text=L'Hopital's%20rule%20is%20a,%7C%3C1%22%20is%20redundant.