# How can we calculate the complex limit $\frac{1 - e^{iz}}{z}$ when $z$ approach zero

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I would like for an explanation how one should approach limit's from the form "$\frac{0}{0}$" in the complex field. Untill now I just used L'hopital, but recently my teacher told us that we do not talk about L'hopital rule in our course (so I did not understand if this rule is true in the complex field). for example, how I can show then without  L'hopital that the following limit is equal to $-i$ when $z$ approach zero  $$\frac{1 - e^{iz}}{z}$$

Comment: Use the standard limit $(e^z-1)/z\to  1$ as $z\to 0$.

Comment: Power series $e^{iz}=1+iz+\frac{(iz)^2}{2}+...$

Comment: @herbsteinberg  thank you, so mostly the general approach to evaluate limits that has the mentioned form will be taylor series?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions)

Comment: Note that the derivative at $0$ of $z\mapsto e^{iz}$ is, by definition of derivative, $\lim_{z\to0}((e^{iz}-1)/z)$, which is the negative of the limit you want. But the derivative of $e^{iz}$ is $ie^{iz}$, whose value at $0$ is $i$. So your limit is $-i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: $B(a, r) = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z - a| < r\}$ for $a \in \Bbb C$ and $r > 0$.

---

Complex differentiable functions have the following very nice property:

> Suppose $a \in \Bbb C$, $r > 0$, and $f : B(a, r) \to \Bbb C$ is complex differentiable.
> Then, we there exists a complex sequence $(a_n)_{n = 0}^\infty$ such $$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(z - a)^n$$ for all $z \in B(a, r)$.

Moreover, the above summation enjoys nice properties, including differentiation term-by-term on $B(a, r)$.

Thus, if $f, g$ are differentiable on a neighbourhood of $0$, then we can write $$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 \cdots}{b_0 + b_1 z + b_2 z^2 + \cdots}$$ on a neighbourhood of $0$.

From the above, depending on how many of the beginning $a_k$ and $b_k$ are $0$, we can calculate the limit. Moreover, we have $$a_k = \frac{1}{k!} f^{(k)}(0)$$ which shows you how L'Hôpital is valid.

In fact, the proof of L'Hôpital is much easier for the case of complex differentiable functions since you have continuity of derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need L'Hopital's rule. By definition, $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z} = f'(0)$. So letting $f(z) = e^{iz}$, we have $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{1 - e^{iz}}{z} = - \lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{e^{iz} - 1}{z} = - \lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z} = - f'(0) = -i e^{i \cdot 0} = -i$.