# L' Hospital's Rule with Complex Numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

$$\lim_{x \to a} {\frac{\sqrt{a+2x}-\sqrt{3x}}{\sqrt{3a+x}-2\sqrt{x}}}, a\neq0, (IIT JEE 1978)$$

My book solves this using rationalization. I solved it using it L' Hospital's Rule. In both cases, the expression with $\sqrt{a}$ cancels, and the final answer is:
$$\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

But all this is assuming Calculus with Real Numbers. However, some parts of the expression will have complex numbers if:
$$a<0\Rightarrow 3x<0 $$

JEE is a grade 12 exam, and doesn't include differentiation of complex functions as part of its syllabus. Hence, this question is a little borderline. It can be solved by just pretending the quantities behave as normal.

But do they? Is there anything to be careful here? Or do the usual rules apply when $a<0$.

(Note: I understand Calculus, but not Complex Analysis.)

Comment: Square roots of complex numbers have two values and  the question assumes that everything is real.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is L'Hopitals rule applicable to complex functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions)

Comment: There's a lot of technical explanation which finally means to say that L'Hopital's rule is applicable with complex variables. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are always dealing with real numbers unless you define the entity $\sqrt {-1}$ as *iota*. The point is that the limiting value of the given function always tends to $2/3\sqrt 3$ regardless of the sign of $a(\ne 0)$. You can verify this by fixing $a=-1$ (say) in the problem.
Further, any function is real as long as the input variable $x$ is real; even though it takes values like $\alpha\sqrt{-1}, \alpha\in\mathbb R$. A complex function involves a complex variable  $z=x+iy, (i=\sqrt{-1})$  as an input.

Comment: What if I want to use L'Hospital's Rule. I am taking the derivative of an expression which includes a complex variable.......

Comment: While using LH rule, you just differentiate a function and then you plug in $x=a$ there. There is no such thing like differentiating a number otherwise the derivative will be zero.

Comment: I corrected my comment. I am differentiating a function, not a number. And if that function can take complex inputs, then it is a complex variable.

Comment: The differentiation rules work similar in complex case too. So as long as you assume that a complex function $f(z)$ is differentiable you can use L-Hopital rule.

Comment: It's a JEE question, and differentiation of complex variables is not in the syllabus. I would like a resolution within exam conditions.

Comment: The problem is that it is still a real function with real input and imaginary output possibly. A complex function can be understood as one from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ with complex input and complex output.